# Get user profile size?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Wait... before you guys come at me about this being asked before, I assure you it's a bit different. I know how to recurse through directories and measure the sum of each container, to include converting it to MB/GB/TB etc..

What I'd like to see if anyone knows is, where does windows determine the profile size? What do I mean? When I click:

- Control Panel
- System
- Advanced
- User Profiles

The profile size is already listed there. Anyone familiar where this is stored at? I queried the `win32_userprofile` with no luck. Just curious about this since I use `Get-ChildItem` as a means of measuring the profile size, and feel like this would be a lot easier since windows seems to already do it for you.

Please feel free to close this question if this isn't suitable to be asked here.

Thank you!

**EDIT:**
*Just ran through the following classes to see if I could find something, but had no luck*

```
Name
----
CIM_UserDevice
Win32_UserAccount
Win32_UserProfile
Win32_LoggedOnUser
Win32_SystemUsers
Win32_UserInDomain
Win32_GroupUser
Win32_UserDesktop
__NTLMUser9X
Win32_RoamingProfileUserConfiguration
Win32_VolumeUserQuota
Win32_RoamingUserHealthConfiguration
Win32_UserStateConfigurationControls
Win32_FolderRedirectionUserConfiguration
Win32_NTLogEventUser
```

I used `Get-WmiObject -List  |Where-Object Name -Match 'User'` to get the above results.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - Don’t comment; Submit an answer; Unnecessary commentary will be flagged. We want answers not temporary commentary

Comment: i suspect - but do NOT know - that it reads the allocation table for that user tree when you open the dialog. it _may_ be getting that info from something like the search index system, but i kinda doubt that. ///// there is nothing that i can find stored in the registry.

Comment: @Lee, hmmm. Will see if I can query the search index and see what I can come up with. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - you are most welcome ... good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: Are you after only local user profiles, or also roaming user profiles?

Comment: @SimonS, we're in a domain environment, so it should be roaming.